# How to efficiently process a large file with a grouping variable in Python

Tags: python

I've got a dataset that looks something like the following:

```
ID   Group
1001 2
1006 2
1008 1
1027 2
1013 1
1014 4
```

So basically, a long list of unsorted IDs with a grouping variable as well.

At the moment, I want to take subsets of this list based on the generation of a random number (imagine they're being drafted, or won the lottery, etc.). Right now, this is the code I'm using to just process it row-by-row, by ID.

```
reader = csv.reader(open(inputname), delimiter=' ')
out1 = open(output1name,'wb')
out2 = open(output2name,'wb')

for row in reader:
    assignment = gcd(1,p,marg_rate,rho)
    if assignment[0,0]==1:
        out1.write(row[0])
        out1.write("\n")
    if assignment[0,1]==1:
        out2.write(row[0])
        out2.write("\n")
```

Basically, i the gcd() function goes one way, you get written to one file, another way to a second, and then some get tossed out. The issue is I'd now like to do this by *Group* rather than ID - basically, I'd like to assign values to the first time a member of the group appears, and then apply it to all members of that group (so for example, if 1001 goes to File 2, so does 1006 and 1027).

Is there an efficient way to do this in Python? The file's large enough that I'm a little wary of my first thought, which was to do the assignments in a dictionary or list and then have the program look it up for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) to generate a random number, but this can be easily replaced.

The idea is to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to have  **single** score (`dict` keys are unique) for a group from the moment it's created:

```
import csv
import random
from collections import defaultdict

reader = csv.DictReader(open(inputname), delimiter=' ')
out1 = open(output1name,'wb')
out2 = open(output2name,'wb')

# create a dictionary with a random default integer value [0, 1] for
# keys that are accessed for the first time
group_scores = defaultdict(lambda: random.randint(0,1))

for row in reader:
    # set a score for current row according to it's group
    # if none found - defaultdict will call it's lambda for new keys
    # and create a score for this row and all who follow
    score = group_scores[row['Group']]
    if score==0:
        out1.write(row['ID'])
        out1.write("\n")
    if score==1:
        out2.write(row['ID'])
        out2.write("\n")

out1.close()
out2.close()
```

I've also used [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) which I find nicer for `csv` files with headers.

**Tip:** you may want to use the [`with` context manager](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to open files.

Example output:

```
reut@sharabani:~/python/ran$ cat out1.txt 
1001
1006
1008
1027
1013
reut@sharabani:~/python/ran$ cat out2.txt 
1014
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a mapping. You can use dicts for that.

Once you've first decided 1001 goes to file 2, you can add to your mapping dict.

```
fileMap={}

fileMap[group]="fileName"
```

And then, when you need to check if the group has been decided yet, you just

```
>>>group in fileMap
True
```

This is instead of mapping every ID to a filename. Just map the groups.

Also, I'm wondering about whether it's worth condsidering batching the writes with .write([aListofLines]).